# properties of measure zero sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X \subset R$ be a Lebesgue measure zero set. Prove that there exists a $p \in R$ such that the set $p + X = \left\{p + x | x \in X\right\}$ has no rational points.

Here is my approach :

Let $p$ be any real number, consider the set of the unions of all rational numbers in $p + X$. 
Since $X$ has measure zero therefore it is countable (? not sure if this is right), then just take out the all the rational points. (Also I am assuming $X$ is not empty)

I think my assumption is not correct so I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: It is conventional here to include your attempts to solve the problem yourself.  And your source (to avoid accusation of plagiarism).  Also, some of our users prefer questions to orders.

Comment: Ditto what GEdgar said.  Prepare for downvotes (not mine).  I think there is an FAQ you should read.

Comment: ops! sorry I got disconnected and could not edit the question.

Answer (score 6):

You are right, it is wrong that all sets of measure $0$ are countable.  See the Cantor set, for example.

If all such sets have rational points, then you can show that $\mathbb R=\bigcup\limits_{r\in\mathbb Q}r+X$, and use countable subadditivity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Since the sets of the form $r + X$ all have measure zero, so does the union by additivity which is R, and this is a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @shm: Yes. ${}$

Answer (score 2):

Given $X$ has measure zero, so does each set $q-X$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}.$ There are only countably many of these, so that their union $A$ also has measure zero. So we may select a point $p$ in the complement of $A$. Then $p+X$ has no rationals, for if say $p+x_1=r$ for a rational number $r$ then $p=r-x_1 \in r-X \subset A,$ but we chose $p$ in the complement of $A.$